# jQuery - fetch array key and value in custom format

Tags: jquery

I have an array

```
var array [] //my array
```

How do I parse my array in this format

```
array[key] ="array[value]", array[key] ="array[value]"
```

and after that warp above parsed array inside

```
[shortcode]  [/shortcode]
```

This is my array

[image: my array]

Comment: You want to have a function parse that second line of code (a string) and let it return a JavaScript array?

Comment: Please rephrase your question.It's fishy.

Comment: please wait, i am doing

Comment: Please do not vote to close,edit is going on..

Comment: It's still unclear to me what you are trying to do. A *concrete* example of input/output would certainly be helpful. Also post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myArray = ["wheel","good","banana","fruit"];

function parseArray(array){
  for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
      array[i] = i+" = array["+array[i]+"]" 
  }
}

parseArray(myArray);

console.log(array) //it outputs 0 = array["wheel"], 1 = array["good"], etc
```

http://jsfiddle.net/steo/eVdKm/1/

Comment: this is javascript, it is a poorly jquery notation

Comment: @elhadi jquery is not javascript?

Comment: @steo, please tell me how to show key

Comment: I'll edit, trying to get what you mean

Comment: fine, its working now

Comment: @steo: yes i know that jquery not javascript and i tell you that your solution is a pure javascript, it is not a jquery.

Comment: lol , dude what are you saying? jQuery is a Javascript library. The problem must be solved with pure javascript because this issue requires only javascript features.